# Converting lowercase to uppercase in Python using recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion, ascii

I am a student relatively new to Python, learning it through classes. We were given a question where we have a list as an input, and we have to convert each element to uppercase. Here is my code so far:

```
def strChange(lst):
    ch=''
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]>='a' and lst[i]<='z' :
            ch+=chr(ord(lst[i])-32)
    return ch
caps =  eval(input("Enter list: "))
caps2 = []
for i in range(len(caps)):
    a = strChange(caps[i])
    caps2.append(a)
print(caps2)
```

And it does the job... But the problem is, it is not using recursion! And I have absolutely no idea where to use it! I am open to all suggestions, but layman's terms are preferred.

Edit: adding example inputs

> input: `['rohit', 'mohan', 'anjali', 'ankit', 'akshit']`
>
> output: `['ROHIT', 'MOHAN', 'ANJALI', 'ANKIT', 'AKSHIT']`

Comment: This is a silly use case for recursion.  Are you sure that was the assignment?  Your entire program could be replaced with one line.

Comment: Could it be that you can have nested lists? ['Rohit', ['Mohan', 'Anjali'], 'Ankit']

Comment: @TimRoberts THAAANK YOU. It makes me so happy to see other people agree! YES it is a very silly use case. And yes, it was the assignment.

Comment: @Majo god i hope not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's silly, but here's how you do it.  You process one character and call the function again for the rest.

```
def strChange(lst):
    if not lst:
        return ''
    ch = lst[0]
    if 'a' <= ch <= 'z':
        ch = chr(ord(ch)-32)
    return ch + strChange(lst[1:])
caps =  eval(input("Enter list: "))
for word in caps:
    print(strChange(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use recursion in case of nested lists? If item in list is list you call same function with it?

```
def strChange(lst):
    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        if type(item) is list:
            strChange(item)
        else:
            lst[index] = item.upper()
    return lst
```